# Variables deleting on startup

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have my variable defined in my class as follows:

```
private static int zombieKills = 0;
```

The problem is, every time I start the application, it sets to 0. I want it to set to 0 ONLY the FIRST time the application starts. So if I set it to, say, 5, it won't reset to 0 when I restart the application.

Comment: Save it in file/database etc.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. What did you try to accomplish this?

Comment: Hint: I would recommend to step back for a second. It seems that you are really on absolute beginner level with java. But you decided to get into the minecraft-programming thing? Really? Honestly: spent some time learning the basics; otherwise chances are high that whatever you come up with ... will be buggy, and not a pleasure for anybody.

Answer (score 4):

Running the application will not change the code. If you want to store data like this it would be best that you store it as a properties file and load it up when you start your application, and save it when ever it is changed.

Oracle tutorial on Properties: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

Small bit of code on how to do it:

```
// saving it
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("zombieKills", String.valueOf(zombieKills));
prop.store(new FileOutputStream(new File("insert file here")), "");

// loading it
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream(new File("insert file here")));
zombieKills = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("zombieKills"));
```

Comment: Thanks. I am a bit confused with that link. How should I do it?

Comment: @Betterjakers use the "Writing Sorted Properties" for saving and "loading properties" for loading them. If you are still confused then try googling "Java Properties" and you will be able to find some other tutorials and source code. Also if you found this answer the most helpful please mark it as correct.

Comment: Is there anyway else to do it? That seems really quite hard. I just don't want my variables to reset on application restart. Is there a way I can do this without reading/writing from files?

Comment: @Betterjakers You have to make your data **persistent** if you want them to not be lost. Writing them to a text-based file is like the absolute simplest way to do that. As commented above: if that is already beyond your skills; then honestly: stop here. You sound like a person that says "me wants to build big skyscraper"; but when you are told "you need to start digging for the basement then"; your answer is "the base-what?"

Comment: Alright, I will try again. Is properties or XML better?

Comment: @Betterjakers I added a brief example to get the idea. And for this I would recommend properties - although you can store properties as xml if you want.

Comment: @Betterjakers Making the `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` will throw a `IOException`. So yes you will want a try catch

Comment: @Betterjakers Well the first thing that your program should do is load the number. And then you can either save each time it is changed, whenever the user indicates that they want to save, or when the program is being closed.

Comment: The number is loaded (It is an integer called "zombieKills"). Do I just copy/paste that code into the place when it should save?

Answer (score 1):

You could check out Minecraft Forge's [Advanced Configuration File](http://minecraftforge.net/wiki/How_to_make_an_advanced_configuration_file).

It is designed for use in Minecraft, and in my opinion is very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only thing you can do to save variables even when the program is stopped is to store them in an extern file (a .txt for instance).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to write the variables on a .txt file :

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("NameOfFile.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

    os.writeInt(zombieKills);

    os.close();
    fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, when you restart the game, you can load back your variable like this :

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("NameOfFile.txt");
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    zombieKills = is.readInt();

    is.close();
    fis.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I put the second bit of code in the preInit method in the main class (I made zombieKills a "public static int") and the first bit of code to run every time the player kills a zombie. Sadly, it does not work and continues to reset to 0 on restart.

Comment: Try putting some `System.out.println()` in both chunks of codes to make sure they get called. Also, check if the file was created. If no files were created, the problem is most likely in the output. If the file is created, and you see stuff in it, the problem is most likely in the input.